# Node.js - accessing a const from a function within http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, api, require

In the code below I am accessing the current bitcoin value in GBP. The console.log works fine.

**value.js**

```
http = require('http');

http.get({
    host: 'api.coindesk.com',
    path: '/v1/bpi/currentprice.json'
    },
    function get_value(response) {
        // Continuously update stream with data
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function(d) { body += d; });
        response.on('end', function() {
                 // Data reception is done, do whatever with it!
                var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
                var final_value = parsed.bpi.GBP.rate
                console.log(final_value)
                module.exports = final_value;
            });
    }
);
```

However when I try to access this value (final_value) from another file:

**server.js**

```
PORT = 4000;
var http = require('http');
const value = require('./value.js');

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.write("Create server working");
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

All I get back is {}.

I'm quite new to node.js and more used to python. I've looked into accessing values from functions within functions but couldn't find any kind of solution.

Does anyone have a recommendation as to how I could access the variable final_value from a separate file?

Comment: It looks like an asynchronous problem. When you import the value.js module, there is no export yet because the request to the api is not completed.
You may export a method in value.js to use it outside to get the final_value.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly prefer to use express than native Node, but given that you are using it, I can give you some tips to help you with it:

If you want to use a js file from other, you should export what you want to share between them. In the example that you are showing it should be something like this (note that I'm exporting the function and also using it as a Promise in a function):

```
const http = require('http');

module.export = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        http.get({
                host: 'api.coindesk.com',
                path: '/v1/bpi/currentprice.json'
            },
            function get_value(response) {
                // Continuously update stream with data
                var body = '';
                response.on('data', function(d) { body += d; });
                response.on('end', function() {
                    // Data reception is done, do whatever with it!
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
                    var final_value = parsed.bpi.GBP.rate
                    console.log(final_value)
                    resolve(final_value);
                });
            }
        );
    });
}
```

then you can use it in your server file in this way:

```
...
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    value.then(result => console.log(result));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change `module.exports = final_value` to `exports.final_value = final_value`, and then retrieve the value with

```js
const { final_value } = require('./value.js');

...

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(final_value);
});
```

The advantage of this is that you can now export other values from the `value.js` file, and just require them in the same way. The main difference between `module.exports` and `exports.value` is that `module.exports` is an object that has `exports` as a property, and `exports` is just an alias for `module.exports`. Essentially, by using the `module.exports` syntax, you are assigning `module.exports` the value of the object you are assigning to it.